# A base class to automatically provide getter and setter functions C++

Tags: c++, c++11

My use case is like.

1. I have some plain fields, which need a basic thread safe getter and setter.
2. For some fields a custom getter and setter is required.

What will be the best approach for this problem?

Comment: Write some getters and setters? If you have to write *many* of them, you should complain to the person who came up with the design, especially if it was you.

Comment: Well, if you are using repository pattern,you may need a *Java Bean* like object to store the data.

Comment: All I am looking for is a typesafe and thread safe way to store and retrieve data, and if if getter or setter expects a custom logic... one can provide that as well.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library provides `atomic` for simple thread-safe getting and setting of values. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Be aware that proper thread safety almost always involves a lot more than wrapping a few members in `std::atomic` and calling it a day.

Answer (score -1):

To directly answer the question, I don't believe there is a single good answer to this.

Unlike C#, C++ doesn't appear to have automatic `get`, `set` generation built into the language, and although there might be a complicated way of doing this "organically" (templates, perhaps?); any solution you might come across might end up being some sort of tool built into an IDE or utility program, such as Eclipse or Code::Blocks.

Additionally, C++ in its C++03 form is not usually inherently thread-safe; support for multi-threading, thread management, async, and memory safety were added on in later versions (C++11 and on), but due to the nature of C++, I don't believe C++ will ever be inherently thread-safe (at least for now).

While `std::atomic<type whatever>` can be a viable option, you might also want to keep in mind that it is indeed an "add-on" to the language and incurs a time cost, like most other constructs with multi-threading (even atomic operations at the processor level are somewhat slower). You could go the route of mutexes, but again, we're going into multi-threading territory, which may be beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "C++ will never be inherently thread-safe"?

Comment: C++ was not originally designed with thread safety because that technology wasn't exactly mainstream at that time, from what I know. C++ didn't originally have a model for multithreading. It was only in C++11 that a multithreaded memory model made it into the core language, and only as a library. C++ is not inherently required to be thread-safe, but it has ample capabilities to be, though, like always, at some sort of performance cost to be overcome by how the programmer uses those features.

Comment: Bjarne says C++17 will focus on concurrency (threading) improvements. "So what is C++17 supposed to be? Here is my first cut: ......
• Provide support for higher-level concurrency models" - https://isocpp.org/files/papers/D4492.pdf